# System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException thrown when trying to instantiate new ViewController

Tags: c#, ios, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have a storyboard. Because I load a view in code (depending on conditions) I haven't used the segue anymore. Now I want to load another view but I'm getting the following error:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was thrown
>   Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

```
ListButton.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
    MyListController myListController = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController ("MyListController") as MyListController;
    myListController.EdgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None;
    if (myListController != null) {
        this.NavigationController.PushViewController (myListController, true);
    }
};
```

When the button (ListButton) is pressed the view should be loaded onto the navigation stack. The error occurs with `InstantiateViewController`.

How can I solve that?

**Edit:**

I went into MyListController and if I comment the following out the view gets loaded:

```
public MyListController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
{
    TableView.RegisterClassForCellReuse (typeof(UITableViewCell), listCellId);
    TableView.Source = new MyListDataSource (this);
    MyList = new List<string> ();
}
```

Log:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Exception: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object   at
>   TestApp.MyListController.ViewDidLoad () [0x0004c] in
>   /Users/xxx/Projects/TestApp/TestApp/TestApp/MyListController.cs:78
>   at at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging:IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper
>   (intptr,intptr)   at
>   MonoTouch.UIKit.UITableViewController.get_TableView () [0x00000] in
>   :0   at TestApp.MyListController..ctor (IntPtr
>   handle) [0x00009] in
>   /Users/xxx/Projects/TestApp/TestApp/TestApp/MyListController.cs:17
>   at at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke
>   (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)   at
>   System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj,
>   System.Object[] parameters) [0x00002] in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:537
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj,
>   System.Object[] parameters) [0x00016] in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:543
>   at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.DoInvoke (System.Object obj,
>   BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder,
>   System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
>   [0x00095] in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:528
>   at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (BindingFlags invokeAttr,
>   System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters,
>   System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:556
>   at System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke (System.Object[]
>   parameters) [0x00000] in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/ConstructorInfo.cs:62
>   at MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.ConstructNSObject[NSObject] (IntPtr
>   ptr, System.Type type, MissingCtorResolution missingCtorResolution)
>   [0x00000] in :0   at
>   MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.ConstructNSObject (IntPtr ptr, IntPtr
>   klass, MissingCtorResolution missingCtorResolution) [0x00000] in
>   :0   at MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.GetNSObject
>   (IntPtr ptr, MissingCtorResolution missingCtorResolution) [0x00000] in
>   :0   at MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.GetNSObject
>   (IntPtr ptr) [0x00000] in :0   at
>   MonoTouch.UIKit.UIStoryboard.InstantiateViewController (System.String
>   identifier) [0x00000] in :0   at
>   TestApp.StartScreenViewController.m__1 (System.Object
>   sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x0000c] in
>   /Users/xxx/Projects/TestApp/TestApp/TestApp/StartScreenViewController.cs:57
>   at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIControlEventProxy.Activated () [0x00000] in
>   :0   at at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain
>   (int,string[],intptr,intptr)   at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main
>   (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String
>   delegateClassName) [0x00000] in :0   at
>   TestApp.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00008] in
>   /Users/xxx/Projects/TestApp/TestApp/TestApp/Main.cs:17

**Try:**
Hmm, now I added a new UITableViewController to the storyboard, changed some classes to public, changed variable names to starting with lower case. Also the old UITableviewController had a problem with an added SearchController. Now I made everything new and the problem only relied in the `viewDidLoad` but that was not the original problem. It was one of these steps (perhaps the SearchController problem).

**Problematic Code:**

```
this.NavigationController.ToolbarHidden = false;
```

It seems that he can't find the `NavigationController` ... How do I addd the navigation controller to the new created view?

Comment: Well a `TargetInvocationException` always has an inner exception saying what actually went wrong - so what does that look like in your case?

Comment: @JonSkeet: How do I view the inner exception? If I go to more details there is a long list (mostly from the system) ...

Comment: Look at the `InnerException` property. If you're logging the full exception, I'd expect it to be there...

Comment: Added the log but SO cuts all carriage returns ...

Comment: It won't if you indent it as if it were code...

Comment: But basically, you've got a `NullReferenceException` in `MyListController.ViewDidLoad`. That's what you need to sort out.

Comment: Now I tried my code in a new project. Here `viewDidLoad` works as expected. The codeline responsible is `this.NavigationController.ToolbarHidden = false;` so he can't find the `NavigationController` ...